# Equating squared sum of Fourier Sine Series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Assume that
>   $$S(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n\sin nx$$
>   is the sum of the Fourier sine series on $[0, \pi]$ for the function $f(x)$ that is equal to $1$ on the interval $[0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ and $0$ on $[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi]$
>
> Evalauate the sum
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{B_n}^2$$
>   Hint: The fourier sine series is equal to the full Fourier series of the odd extension of $f$

So with a bit of elbow grease, one would get
$$B_n = \frac{2}{n\pi}$$
I believe the idea of the problem is to not use the famous sum for $\frac{1}{n^2}$. However, this hint has me lost, since our extension was odd, don't the $A_n$ cosine Fourier coefficients disappear? I computed them and they did so. I am not sure what information this hint gives me. I was thinking about perhaps trying to rewrite the problem in a way that yields Parseval's identity, but I cannot think of anything clever (or obvious) which would get the proper sum indexing.

Comment: $\sum_n B_n^2 = {1 \over 2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi S(x)^2 dx$, where $S$ is taken to be odd. $S^2$ is easy to integrate from the definition of $S$ (**not** the Fourier series!).

Comment: So you can apply Parseval's even though the sum does not range from $-\infty$ to $\infty$?

Comment: Well, if you are using complex coefficients you would sum over $\mathbb{Z}$ but here you are summing the $A_n,B_n$ except all the $A_n$s are zero.